# Enable lazy loading for the particular block of code

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I disabled the lazy loading in context but now in for some cases I want to use lazy loading in my code but don't want to enable it through the context.

Is there is any way to enable it for the particular block of codes.

Comment: You need to post code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/01/31/using-dbcontext-in-ef-feature-ctp5-part-6-loading-related-entities.aspx

```
// I use princesses because ponies are too mainstream
var princesses2 = context.Princesses
                          .Include("Unicorns")
                          .ToList();
```

You simply *include* the relationship